# enum without a typedef or a name

Tags: c++, c, contiki

I am trying to understand some opensource code

I have come across a line of code that resembles

```
enum {
   Thing1,
   Thing2,
};
```

I was wondering how does this enum work? it has no name or typedef

The actual lines of code can be found [here](https://github.com/contiki/contiki-2.x/blob/master/core/net/rime/collect.h) in lines 125 - 128

Comment: itsa an anonymous enum. the `Thing1` and `Thing2` have the same scope as that of the enum itself. with them having 0 and 1 int value resp.

Answer (score 3):

This is a traditional anonymous enumeration. The traditional enums exports its symbols to the enclosing namespace:

```
namespace a{
enum {
    Thing1, // a::Thing1
    Thing2, // a::Thing2
};
}
```

So in this anonymous enumeration, you don't need to specify the enum name to reffer its members, but it could lead to name clashes, due to the behaviour of exporting symbols to the enclosing namespace:

```
namespace a{
enum {
    Thing1, // a::Thing1
    Thing2, // a::Thing2
};

enum namedEnum {
    Thing1, // Error!
    Thing2, // Error!
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This construction can be used for named constants where the actual value is uninteresting and the only requirement is that the values of the constants differ.

Comment: It's not about the values of the enumerators; `enum { Thing1 = 0, Thing2 = 0 };` is perfectly fine. It means only that you can't created a named object of that type, because the type doesn't have a name: `enum MyThings { Thing1, Thing2 }; MyThings my_thing = Thing1;` -- can't do that if `MyThings` isn't there.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, I thought it was pretty obvious that you can't create an object of an anonymous type. But I distinctly remember that this was used for constants like `enum { Val1 = 10, Val2 = 11 }` with  duplicate-checks for free.

Comment: `enum` types are allowed to have duplicate values for their enumerators. Try it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Right. Damn. You only get that safety if you don't manually specify the values. Okay, my bad.